# How to convert date to datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

I have this type of date '20181115 0756' and also in a diffent dataframe in this format '2018-11-15'. I would like to know if there is any way to convert it to datetime without the hours and minutes

`date['DATE']= pd.to_datetime(date.DATE)`

this converts it to 218-11-15 00:00:00 and I'd like to avoid that

What I trying to do is to calcuate the time difference between the dates in the two dataframes that I have

Thank you in advance

Comment: Take a look at [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse strings of a certain format into dateteime objects. Also note the difference between [`date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects), [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects), and [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) objects, you’re probably looking for `date`.

Comment: so I have the dataframe date['date']. The command would be date.datetime.strptime(date.date."%YYYY%mm%dd %HH%MM"). Also the dtype for this column is object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
date['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(date['DATE'], errors='coerce').dt.date
```

Comment: When I try that I get "Unknown string format". The dtype is object for this column. Could that be why?

Comment: What is the data type on your original column? You could use errors='coerce' as an argument to see what is causing the error.

Comment: the dtype for the orginal column is object

Comment: Then use errors='coerce' or errors='ignore' and check against your original. It may be some sort of issue with one or more of the strings you're trying to convert.